# for loop, Math.random() not acting as intended

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to code a dice game in javascript, using Math.random() to generate the values of the dice and an array to hold the current values of each individual die.

The problems I'm having are 1), the array ends up containing six numbers, and the loop only runs five times, and 2) I can't figure out how to get Math.random() to return different numbers on each dice roll.

Here's the function in question:

```
var array = []

function rollDice() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {

        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

        array[i] = roll;
        //array.splice(i, 1, roll);
    }
}
```

You can see that 'i' iterates from zero to four in the loop (which equals five loops), and on each loop another random number is generated and inserted into the array at the equivalent place.

Regarding the number of items in the array: if I run the code as written above, I'll get something like this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined].
If I run it using the commented line with the 'splice' function (which should remove the value stored at place 'i' and replace it with a new value,) I'll get [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. How is this happening if the loop is only running five times?

As to the difficulty I'm having getting the random numbers to change more reliably: I've tried the following in my loop...

```
var roll;
while (roll === hand[i] || roll === null) {
    roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
```

...in the hopes that 'roll' will keep spinning random numbers until it comes up with a different one, but no dice. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I've added an explicit array declaration since I didn't make it clear enough that my array was in fact being explicitly declared before.

Comment: Try `array[array.length]=roll;`. Also, you are missing the line `var array=[];` before the loop. Or use `for (var roll = i = 0, array = []; i <= 4; i++)` instead, which is the preferable way. And remove the `var` on `var roll = [...];`.

Comment: Your code looks good, check it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gaq9q4u/)

Comment: You need to make sure you declare your array; you didn't post that portion of your code. The `while` loop doesn't work probably because `roll` will start off as `undefined`, not `null`, so the loop won't run at all.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion regarding my array. It is being explicitly and correctly declared, I just left the declaration out of my code snippet because I assumed my readers would take that as a given. I shall now assume nothing and have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is.  Do you want 5 random numbers with no repeats?  Is that what you're trying to do?  If not, please explain because you are successfully generating 5 random numbers with your first block of code.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel Please see my edit and revise your response. Also, as I'm still something of a novice with Javascript, I prefer to avoid coding shorthand for now, whether shorthand is the 'preferred' way or not.

Comment: @bmurrell30 What shorthands? o.O

Comment: The code seems to work fine here:http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/frh3dyvd/

Comment: @jfriend00 My goal is this: if, at the time my function runs, my currently stands as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], then by the time the function finishes running each number in the array will be something different. So index [0] will be anything other than 1, index [1] will be anything other than 2, and so on.

Comment: Geez.  That is NOT what your question conveys.  Please edit this clarification into your question so people understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @bmurrell30 That makes no sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working as you intended.

Mistakes in your code:

1. <del>`array` is undefined</del> It's declared **outside**
2. <del>You are defining properties of an `undefined` variable.</del>
3. You are incorrectly using your `while` loop.
4. <del>Your function doesn't return anything.</del> (Since the array is declared outside the loop, this is an unnecessary point.)

Here is revised code, using `for`:

```
function rollDice() {
    for (var i = 0, array = []; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        array[array.length] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Changes:

1. Removed the useless `roll` variable.
2. Used the property `length` to set the next position (similar to `array.push(value)` but *faster*).
3. Declared the `array`
4. Returned the value to be assigned outside the function

Using a `do ... while` loop:

```
function rollDice() {
    var array = [];
    do
    {
        array[array.length] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    }
    while ( array.length < 5 );
    return array;
}
```

Differences:

1. The variable `i` isn't needed anymore.
2. Direct declaration and increment of the `array.length`
3. You only check the length at the end, which is one less useless check
4. It's **faster**!!!

   ---

Regarding the (pevious) edit:

**DON'T DO THAT!!!**

Don't access a variable declared *outside* a function.

That's the most error-prone way of doing it!

Comment: The downvote wasn't my doing. Or if it was, it was made in error. I haven't even tested your code in my project yet. One moment.

Comment: @bmurrell30 Take your time. And please, edit your question with what you said in the comments.

Comment: @bmurrell30 - now you've accepted this answer that doesn't do what you said you wanted in the comments (no repeat in the same slot).  I give up with you.  Your question is not clear and your votes don't match what you asked for.  It is not worth trying to help you apparently when you are going to be this unclear.

Comment: @jfriend00 According to what is written **in the question**, this matches the description. I'm still waiting for the update to the question so I can change mine. But what can I do...?

Comment: My comment was addressed to bmurrell30, not to you.  See the @bmurrell30 at the beginning of my comment.  That's who it is addressed to.  So far, most unclear question of the day.  If the OP just wants to fill the array with 5 random numbers, their original code already works as shown in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/frh3dyvd/.  It remains unclear what they are actually asking.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just flag it. Also, it was in my answer which is indirectly directed to me. I got the notification...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - you should understand that on StackOverflow, regardless of whether you are notified or not, when a comment starts out with @ somename, that's who the comment is directed at.  I've voted to close the OP's question as "Unclear What They Are Asking".  Not much else I can do except express my frustration with the OP for being so obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

To return 5 unique numbers between 1 and 5 randomly:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

function rollDice() {
    array.sort(function(){
        return Math.random() - 0.5;
    });
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wrgrr0v/1/

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have clarified that what you want is that successive calls to `roll()` will not repeat a value in that particular slot in the array, you can do that with this:

```
function rollDice() {
    var roll;
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        // keep generate a new random value until it is different
        // than what was in this slot of the array before
        while ((roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1) === array[i]) {}
        array[i] = roll;
    }
}
```

Working demo:http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/frh3dyvd/